# Read duplicate column names in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a file with many columns and need to read some of them using pandas. The problem is that there are repeated names among the columns that I need. In this case, the parameter `mangle_dupe_cols` does not seem to be working. It just returns the first occurrence of the columns I asked for.

---

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv = r'''a;b;c;d;c;d;e;f
1;11;21;31;41;51;61;71
2;12;22;32;42;52;62;72
3;13;23;33;43;53;63;73
4;14;24;34;44;54;64;74
5;15;25;35;45;55;65;75'''
```

If I read the whole file, without specifying columns to read, I get the expected answer:

```
df = pd.read_csv( StringIO(csv), 
        sep=';', header=0)

print( df )

   a   b   c   d  c.1  d.1   e   f
0  1  11  21  31   41   51  61  71
1  2  12  22  32   42   52  62  72
2  3  13  23  33   43   53  63  73
3  4  14  24  34   44   54  64  74
4  5  15  25  35   45   55  65  75
```

However, I would like to specify some columns only, like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv( StringIO(csv), 
        usecols=[ 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'd',], 
        sep=';', header=0)

print( df )
```

... in which case I only get the first occurrence of the repeated columns:

```
    b   c   d
0  11  21  31
1  12  22  32
2  13  23  33
3  14  24  34
4  15  25  35
```

I would like to avoid reading the whole file, look for the columns and drop those which I don't need, because the files are somewhat big.

Is it possible to specify columns AND get duplicated columns using `pandas.read_csv()`?

I will be very grateful for any hints!

---

Using `python 3.7.5` , `pandas 0.25.0`

Comment: What about `['b', 'c', 'd', 'c.1', 'd.1']`?

Comment: If that doesn't work, read the file and then filter those columns from the DF afterward.

Comment: @Barmar That seems the way to go, yes. Works well with CezarySzulc's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use this:

```
In [40]:

df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv', index_col=0)
df
Out[44]:
a   b   a.1
0   4   2   1
1   5   3   2
2   6   4   3
In [41]:

df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv', index_col=0, nrows=0)
# read only column names
In [42]:

df
Out[42]:
a   b   a.1
In [36]:

use_col = [col_name for col_name in list(df.columns) if col_name.startswith('a')]
# check how many columns we have and save them to the separate list
In [39]:

df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv', usecols=use_col)
In [40]:

df
Out[40]:
a   a.1
0   4   1
1   5   2
2   6   3
In [ ]:
```

Answer (score 1):

I post this answer, following [that of CezarySzulc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59936399/776515) for the sake of completeness, to have it as a bit of documentation.

The trick is to make first use of pandas' functionality to detect and rename columns, make changes and then read the actual file.

With the example in the question:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv = r'''a;b;c;d;c;d;e;f
1;11;21;31;41;51;61;71
2;12;22;32;42;52;62;72
3;13;23;33;43;53;63;73
4;14;24;34;44;54;64;74
5;15;25;35;45;55;65;75'''
```

The following 2 lines make it work:

```
# Get lines in the file, repeated ones will have a suffix already
cols_in_file = list( pd.read_csv( StringIO(csv), sep=';', nrows=1 ) )
# Select only the columns desired, using the point to check for the repeated
cols_to_read = [ c for c in cols_in_file if c.split('.')[0] in [ 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'd',] ]

df = pd.read_csv( StringIO(csv), 
        usecols=cols_to_read, 
        sep=';', header=0)

print( df )

    b   c   d  c.1  d.1
0  11  21  31   41   51
1  12  22  32   42   52
2  13  23  33   43   53
3  14  24  34   44   54
4  15  25  35   45   55
```

This method has the plus that it works with any number of repeated columns without changes in the code:

```
csv = r'''a;b;c;d;c;d;e;f;c
1;11;21;31;41;51;61;71;81
2;12;22;32;42;52;62;72;82
3;13;23;33;43;53;63;73;83
4;14;24;34;44;54;64;74;84
5;15;25;35;45;55;65;75;85'''

cols_in_file = list( pd.read_csv( StringIO(csv), sep=';', nrows=1 ) )
cols_to_read = [ c for c in cols_in_file if c.split('.')[0] in [ 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'd',] ]

df = pd.read_csv( StringIO(csv), 
        usecols=cols_to_read, 
        sep=';', header=0)

print( df )

    b   c   d  c.1  d.1  c.2
0  11  21  31   41   51   81
1  12  22  32   42   52   82
2  13  23  33   43   53   83
3  14  24  34   44   54   84
4  15  25  35   45   55   85
```

The checkup with the point will break if there are points in the column names in the file, of course. That would need another fix on top.