# Pandas read csv only returns the first column when column names are duplicate

Tags: python, pandas, csv, fastapi

I have OHLC data in a .csv file with the stock name is repeated in the header rows, like this:

```
M6A=F, M6A=F,M6A=F, M6A=F, M6A=F
Open, High, Low, Close, Volume
```

I am using *pandas read_csv* to get it, and parse all (and only) the 'M6A=F' columns to FastAPI. So far nothing I do will get *all* the columns. I either get the first column if I filter with *"usecols="* or the last column if I filter with *"names="*.

I don't want to load the entire .csv file then dump unwanted data due to speed of use, so need to filter before extracting the data.

Here is my code example:

```
symbol = ['M6A=F']
df = pd.read_csv('myOHCLVdata.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=lambda x: x in symbol)

def parse_csv(df):
    res = df.to_json(orient="records")
    parsed = json.loads(res)
    return parsed

@app.get("/test")
def historic():
    return parse_csv(df)
```

What I have done so far:
I checked the documentation for `pandas.read_csv` and it says "names=" will not allow duplicates.
I use `lambdas` in the above code to prevent the symbol hanging FastAPI if it does not match a column.
My understanding from other stackoverflow questions on this is that `mangle_dupe_cols=True` should be incrementing the duplicates with  `M6A=F.1, M6A=F.2, M6A=F.3 etc...` when pandas reads it into a dataframe, but that isn't happening and I tried setting it to false, but it says it is not implemented yet.
Other answers I found in [this stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39986959/9594269) don't seem to tally with what is happening in my code, since I am only getting the first column returned, or the last column with the others over-written. (I included FastAPI code here as it might be related to the issue or a workaround).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59935835/read-duplicate-column-names-in-csv-file. This has the solution you are looking for - the trick is to read the first row, then provide the column names as `M6A=F.1, M6A=F.2,...` to `usecols`.

Comment: this worked and in the absence of something simpler I will use it. I had seen that, but had thought it was a bodge workaround as it was over 2 years old.

Comment: For returning the DataFrame in JSON format, please don't use your current approach. Instead. please have a look at Option 1 (**Updates** 1 or 2) of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71205127/17865804).

Comment: @Chris a copy of that exact doco elsewhere is where I got the original approach from. Can you explain why its a bad approach that I chose? I will test out the one you suggested though, thanks.

Comment: @Chris. I tested update 1 and got ```ValueError: Out of range float values are not JSON compliant``` but update 2 using ```Response``` method works okay. I'd still like to know why it matters to use that rather than what I was using.

Comment: The reason is simply because, using your approach, you are first converting the DataFrame into JSON (using `df.to_json()`), then that JSON into `dict` (using `json.loads()`), and finally, when you return the `dict` from the endpoint, FastAPI, behind the scenes, automatically converts that return value into JSON again, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71205127/17865804).