# Python: Import of csv file with duplicate column names

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, import

I'm trying to import a file via pd.read_csv. This also works quite well. Only I have the problem that there are several columns with the same name in the source file:

`Row A, Row B, Row B, Row C`

However, only the first column is taken into account during the import. The corresponding DataFrame looks like this:

`Row A, Row B, Row C`

I need a solution that imports all spades, but renames them if necessary. So something like this:

`Row A, Row B_1, Row B_2, Row C`

I'm currently using the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('new.csv', header = 0, usecols = ["Row A", "Row B", "Row B", "Row C"], sep = ',')
```

The ability to rename the columns in the original file is not practical. This is because column B can occur as often as you like.

I also tried

```
df = pd.read_csv('new.csv', header = 0, usecols = ["Row A", "Row B", "Row B", "Row C"], sep = ',')
```

But the result was the same.

Thank you very much in advance.
Oliver

Comment: What version of Pandas are you using? I'm using 2.0.3 and when I read a csv with columns with the same name, it rename it. A,B,B,C goes to A,B,B.1,C.
I didn't specify columns when reading, I only used read_csv('new.csv')

Comment: This looks like an answer you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59935835/read-duplicate-column-names-in-csv-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot. I learned a lot and also found an other possibility, I implemented in my program:
I imported all columns but the "B" columns. Then I imported all "B" columns using a lambda function and at last I merged both:

```
df = pd.read_csv('new.csv', header = 0, usecols = ["A", "C"], sep = ',')
df_1 = pd.read_csv('new.csv', header = 0, usecols = lambda x: x.startswith("B") | x.startswith("A"), sep = ',')
df = df.merge(left_on = "A", right_on = "A", right = df_1, how = "left")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first read the CSV as text, modify the header line to make each column name unique, and then read it into a DataFrame.

```
with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

header = lines[0].strip().split(',')

col_count = {}
new_header = []

for col in header:
    if col in col_count:
        col_count[col] += 1
        new_col = f"{col}_{col_count[col]}"
    else:
        col_count[col] = 1
        new_col = col
    new_header.append(new_col)

lines[0] = ','.join(new_header) + '\n'

with open('modified_data.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)

df = pd.read_csv('modified_data.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

column2 = df['Row B']
column3 = df['Row B.1']

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).